# Rails Tutorial test_layout_links test failure

Tags: ruby-on-rails, railstutorial.org

I have been doing the Harl tutorial and this issue hasn't caused huge problems, but I can't figure out why my test cannot find the link to the 'contact' page. Any pointers in the right direction are appreciated.

```
Controller:
class StaticPagesController < ApplicationController
 def home
 end

 def help
 end

 def about
 end

 def contact
 end 
end

site_layout_test.rb
require 'test_helper'

class SiteLayoutTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
test "layout links" do
  get root_path
  assert_template 'static_pages/home'
  assert_select "a[href=?]", root_path
  assert_select "a[href=?]", help_path
  assert_select "a[href=?]", contact_path
  assert_select "a[href=?]", about_path
  end
end

routes.rb 
Rails.application.routes.draw do

root 'static_pages#home'
get 'help' => 'static_pages#help'
get 'about' => 'static_pages#about'
get 'contact' => 'static_pages#contact'
get 'signup' => 'users#new' 
resources :users 

end
```

this is the only place the link is, in the

```
_footer.html.erb
<footer class="footer">
  <small>
    The <a href="http://www.railstutorial.org/">Ruby on Rails Tutorial</a> by <a href="http://www.michaelhartl.com/">Michael Hartl</a>
</small>
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><%= link_to "About", about_path %></li>
        <li><%= link_to "Contact", contact_path %></li>
        <li><a href="http://railstutorial.org/">News</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

and this is the error message I get:

```
1) Failure:
  SiteLayoutTest#test_layout_links [/home/will/rails/sample_app/test/integration/site_layout_test.rb:9]:
  Expected at least 1 element matching "a[href="/contact"]", found 0..
  Expected 0 to be >= 1.
```

Here is the contact template:
     <% provide(:title, "Contact") %>

## Contact

Contact the Ruby on Rails Tutorial about the sample app at the contact page.

Here is the layout for application.html.erb

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
 <title><%= full_title(yield(:title)) %></title>
 <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
 <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
 <%=  render 'layouts/shim' %>
 </head>
 <body>
    <%= render 'layouts/header' %>
    <div class="container">
        <%= yield %>
        <%= render 'layouts/footer' %>
        <%= debug(params) if Rails.env.development? %>
    <div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: Show us your template files as well.

Comment: The application.html.erb template? the contact page template?

Comment: If you navigate to the page does the contact link show up in your browser?

Comment: Yes, if I click the link running on the local host, I get the /contact in the address bar.

Comment: After `get root_path` at your test, add `puts response.body` and add the result to the answer. You could also add your layout file.

Comment: I added puts response.body after get root_path like you suggested and nothing changed really.

Comment: After looking again at the result of the response.body, I noticed the home.html.erb had an extra </html> that caused the test to stop reading the code before it got to where the link was and thus caused it to fail because it didn't continue to read down to where the link was.  Thank you so much for the heads up man.  Add your comment as an answer so I can vote it up.

Answer (score 0):

After `get root_path` at your test, add `puts response.body` and add the result to the answer. You could also add your layout file.

Answer (score 0):

Just solved this similar error - mine was on the 'about' page however.

Remove `!DOCTYPE html` & any other `html` written from your **contact.html.erb** files.

Run test and you should be good to go!